Complete locally convex topological vector spaces are not stable under extension
I've heard that complete locally convex topological vector spaces are not stable under extension. However, I don't know of any example. What would be an example of a complete topological vector space $X$ and a closed subspace $Y \subseteq X$ such that both $Y$ and $X/Y$ are locally convex, but $X$ is not locally convex?
